# How to put the plot together?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, image, plot-themes

I have a very long code which at the end, I get two plot (main energy plot and energy bar attached pictures). I need these two plots next to each other (for paper). Problem is I can not save the pictures to gather, and they are in two different boxes, and I have to save them one by one then put them together manually. This my code

```
    ListContourPlot[graphpointogather3d3,
      PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 1550, 
   LegendLabel -> "\[CapitalDelta]G(kT)", 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 100, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
     Black, Bold}], ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 8}}], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False

 , FrameLabel -> {{"Number of Contacts", 
    None}, {"End to End Distance(\[Angstrom])", "All K Acylated"}}, 
 ImageSize -> Full, PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All, None}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 80, Thickness[0.01]], 
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], 
 RotateLabel -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 100}, AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotRange -> {{2, 85}, {20, 130}}


 ]
```

and this the result of the code: the main energy plot 
[image]

and This the energy bar which I need to be next to the main plot:
[image]

At the end I need something Like this Picture:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are making the image too large to fit on the screen. I know that you are seeking a high quality image but I think you can work with a smaller image size.

I created some fake data because I didn't have access to `graphpointogather3d3`.

```
graphpointogather3d3 = 
  Flatten[Table[{x, y, N[Cosh[(x - 80)/20*(y - 15)/20]]}, {x, 27, 
     118}, {y, 5, 70}], 1];
```

I changed `ImageSize` to be 600 and divided all of your dimensions by 4 (e.g., `FontSize`, `LegendMarkerSize`, `FrameTickStyle`, ...)

```
ListContourPlot[
 graphpointogather3d3,
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[
   Automatic,
   LegendMarkerSize -> 1550/4,
   LegendLabel -> "\[CapitalDelta]G(kT)",
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 100/4, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
     Black, Bold}
   ],
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 8}}],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 FrameLabel -> {{"Number of Contacts", 
    None}, {"End to End Distance(\[Angstrom])", "All K Acylated"}},
 ImageSize -> 600,
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All, None}},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 80/4, Thickness[0.01/4]],
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"],
 RotateLabel -> True,
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 100/4},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotRange -> {{2, 85}, {20, 130}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Update

In order to make the bar the same size and position of the main plot, adjust `LegendMarkerSize` and `LegendMargins` until they match.

```
ListContourPlot[
 graphpointogather3d3,
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[
   Automatic,
   LegendMarkerSize -> 1550/2.7,
   LegendLabel -> "\[CapitalDelta]G(kT)",
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 100/4, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
     Black, Bold},
   LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {40, 0}}
   ],
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 8}}],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 FrameLabel -> {{"Number of Contacts", 
    None}, {"End to End Distance(\[Angstrom])", "All K Acylated"}},
 ImageSize -> 600,
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific", Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All, None}},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 80/4, Thickness[0.01/4]],
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"],
 RotateLabel -> True,
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 100/4},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotRange -> {{2, 85}, {20, 130}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How can I change the size of the bar and make it the high of the main plot?

Comment: Adjust `LegendMarkerSize` and `LegendMargins` in order to get it to align with the main plot. See update.